# How to initiate warming when a cache is created?

Tags: ignite

I'd like to to use an Ignite cluster to warm a [`PARTITIONED`](http://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheMode.html#PARTITIONED) cache from an existing database. The existing database is not partitioned and expensive to scan, so I'd like to perform a single scan when the cache is created by the cluster. Once the job completes, the result would be a cache containing all data from the existing database partitioned and evenly distributed across the cluster.

How do you implement a job that runs when a cache is created by Ignite?

Answer (score 2):

Ignite integrates with underlying stores via `CacheStore` [1] implementations. Refer to [2] for details about your particular use case.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

Comment: Thanks @Valentin. When using a `CacheStore`, from where should `IgniteCache.loadCache` be called? When using `IgniteDataStreamer`, from where should `addData` be called? It seems that service does not work because there is no guarantee `execute` will only be called once for the life of the cluster. Alternatively, `EVT_CACHE_STARTED` seems to be published locally on every node, so grid events will not work. Generally speaking, the question is where to implement exactly-once-per-cache logic, such as cache warming.

Comment: You can create a client node, call `IgniteCache.loadCache` and stop the client when the process is done. The same goes for `IgniteDataStreamer`, generally it will be a client node that loads the data from a DB and streams it into server nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Service](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/services/Service.html) that runs once on cluster start and then cancels itself. It can use a cache to store state, so it will not run if it's deployed in the cluster a second time.

The following abstract Service runs `executeOnce` once per cluster the first time it's deployed after cluster start:

```
abstract class ExecuteOnceService extends Service {

  val ExecuteOnceCacheName = "_execute_once_service"

  val config = new CacheConfiguration[String, java.lang.Boolean](ExecuteOnceCacheName)
    .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
    .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)

  @IgniteInstanceResource
  var ignite: Ignite = _

  override def execute(ctx: ServiceContext): Unit = {
    val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(config)
    val executed = cache.getAndPutIfAbsent(ctx.name(), java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)
    if (executed != java.lang.Boolean.TRUE) executeOnce(ctx)
    ignite.services().cancel(ctx.name())
  }

  def executeOnce(ctx: ServiceContext): Unit

}
```

Comment: @valentin Thx for your answer. Do you think this is a reasonable approach?